# Increasing/decreasing notation

Tags: notation

I've seen the following notation being used when someone is talking about right-continuous functions:

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow x_0^+} F_X(x) = F_X(x_0),$$

$$\lim_{x \downarrow x_0} F_X(x) = F_X(x_0).$$

Which is the preferred notation, or are both okay?

Comment: They're both fine.

Comment: Both are okay. The first is more common, but that doesn't mean there is anything wrong with the second. You may even see it written simply as $F_X(x_0^+)$.

Comment: Ok, thanks very much.